# JS filter not working inside another filter

Tags: javascript, filter

I need to get filtered tabs. Only those where fields are from "stack" list.
So I need to filter "fields" array first and if there is nothing then exclude col, row, or tab

```
var tabs = [
  {
    "name": "Main Tab",
    "layout": {
      "label": "side",
      "rows": [
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["name"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["status"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["model"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["office"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["room"] } ]
      ]
    }
  },{
    "name": "Second Tab",
    "layout": {
      "label": "side",
      "rows": [
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["type"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["ip"] } ]
      ]
    }
  },{
    "name": "Last Tab",
    "layout": {
      "label": "side",
      "rows": [
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["office"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["location"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["address"] } ]
      ]
    }
  }
]

var stack = ["location","address","room","office"]
```

But it is not working. Do not get it at all.

Trying this way:

```
var filtered_tabs = tabs.filter(tab=>tab.layout.rows.filter(row=>row.filter(obj=>obj.fields.filter(field=>stack.indexOf(field)>-1).length>0).length>0).length>0)
```

Expect this result:

```
var filtered_tabs = [
  {
    "name": "Main Tab",
    "layout": {
      "label": "side",
      "rows": [
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["office"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["room"] } ]
      ]
    }
  },{
    "name": "Last Tab",
    "layout": {
      "label": "side",
      "rows": [
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["office"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["location"] } ],
        [ { "col": 12, "fields": ["address"] } ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

But I get the same tabs array

Comment: The javascript you have provided is really not maintainable. Just a bit of advice - just because you can do it in one line doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var tabs = [
  {
    name: "Main Tab",
    layout: {
      label: "side",
      rows: [
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["name"] }],
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["status"] }],
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["model"] }],
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["office"] }],
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["room"] }]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Second Tab",
    layout: {
      label: "side",
      rows: [[{ col: 12, fields: ["type"] }], [{ col: 12, fields: ["ip"] }]]
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Last Tab",
    layout: {
      label: "side",
      rows: [
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["office"] }],
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["location"] }],
        [{ col: 12, fields: ["address"] }]
      ]
    }
  }
];

var stack = ["location", "address", "room", "office"];

console.log(tabs.map(x => (x.layout.rows = x.layout.rows.filter(row => stack.includes(row[0].fields[0]) ), x))
    .filter(x => x.layout.rows.length));
```